# how to "blame" on selection using bzr explorer or via console?

Tags: intellij-idea, bazaar, blame

I want to do something like git blame - not on a whole file

but on a code snippet (selection)

how can I do this in bzr (console or bzr explorer) ?

Answer (score 1):

If you have configured git root in your project (Settings | Version Control) then you can open annotations via right click on gutter, or via menu VCS | Git | Annotate.

Comment: I would imagine doing the same for bazaar would be quite similar.